# Parse JSON can not get value

Tags: php, json, html

My PHP cote return error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$paging in   Trying to get property of non-object 
>   Use of undefined constant total_items - assumed 'total_items' in

How can I get `total_items`  value?

This is JSON:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "total_items": 0,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 0
     },
     "data": [],
     "facets": null
}
```

```php
$content = file_get_contents($urll); 
$clean_content = removeBomUtf8($content); 
$decoded = json_decode($clean_content); 

foreach ($decoded->data as $data) 
{ 
    $total_items = (string)$data->paging[0]->total_items; 
    echo total_items; 
} ;
```

Comment: why are you trying loop through `$decoded->data` if it is an empty array? And to get `total_items` value from that json it would be just `$decoded->paging->total_items` without any loop.

Answer (score 1):

tyr this.

```
$data ='{"paging":{"total_items":0,"current_page":1,"total_pages":0},"data":[],"facets":null}';

$v = json_decode($data,true);
echo $v['paging']['current_page'];
```

Comment: It would totally work with objects as well, but yeah, converting to associative array is also an option.